# How to replace only one digit in text in python?

Tags: python-3.x, text, file-io, replace

I have a file with pairs of numbers as following:

```
0,21
0,52
0,464
100,478
1,101
1,729
1,730
```

And I want to replace the single "0"s with "2000". The expected output should be:

```
2000,21
2000,52
2000,464
100,478
1,101
1,729
1,730
```

However, with my code, it changes all 0s to 2000s and I end up with this output:

```
2000,21
2000,52
2000,464
120002000,478
1,120001
1,729
1,732000
```

My code is:

```
textToSearch = "0"
textToReplace = "2000"
fileToSearch = "example.csv"
with fileinput.FileInput(fileToSearch, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')
```

Plus : I never know how many 0s will be on the left side of the comma, therefore I cannot limit the number of 0s to be changed. The file is randomly generated, as sometimes I have twelve 0s and sometimes only one.
I have tried this:

```
textToSearch = "0,"
textToReplace = "2000,"
fileToSearch = "example.csv"
with fileinput.FileInput(fileToSearch, inplace=True, backup='.bak') as file:
    for line in file:
        print(line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace), end='')
```

However,this time it is not working for numbers such as `"100"` or `"200"`, as it is making them `"102000"` and `"202000"` respectively.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is slightly modified to save your data to file. The basic algorithm hasn't changed.

```
import re

temp = []

with open("example.csv", "r") as inputf:
    for line in inputf:
        line = line.strip("\n")
        match = re.search("^0", line)
        if match:
            list1 = line.split(",")
            list1[0] = 2000
            line = str(list1[0]) + "," + str(list1[1])
        temp.append(line)
inputf.close()

# overwrite original file

with open("example.csv", "w") as outputf:
    for item in temp:
        outputf.write(item + "\n")
outputf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using "regular expressions" import re module as below.

```
import re    

fileToSearch = "example.csv"

    with open(fileToSearch) as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip("\n")
            match = re.search("^0", line)
            if match:
                list1 = line.split(",")
                list1[0] = 2000
                line = str(list1[0]) + "," + str(list1[1])
            print(line)
```

This seems to produce the result you want.

Comment: Thank you! I am not able to write the output(lines) to a file. I have changed as with open(fileToSearch,'w') as file and added file.write(line) at the end. However, doesnt work. Do you perhaps know why?

Answer (score 0):

KISS methodology. While playing around with regexp, I came up with an even shorter and simpler solution that you might like to consider using.

```
import re        

with open("example.csv", "r") as inputf:

    randstr = inputf.read()
    regex = re.compile(r"\b0\b")
    result = re.sub(regex, "2000", randstr)

with open("example.csv", "w") as outputf:
    outputf.write(result)
```